# vb.net select between two dates

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

I need some help. I want to find a birthday in a selected month, for example is this.

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE DOB between '1777-01-01' AND '3000-01-31';
```

They only get the year. How can I get the value of month I selected?

Comment: So you're saying that you want records from any year in a range but only within a specific month in any of those years, right?

Comment: failed to enable constraints. one or more rows contains values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.. sir here's the error when I generate it to a reports..

Answer (score 0):

To get a particular month regardless of year, you may want to do this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%e %M') AS birthday
  FROM students
 WHERE MONTH(DOB) = 1
 ORDER BY DAY(DOB)
```

for January.  This will scan your table and pick up all the January DOB values and order them by the day in January of their birthdays.

Comment: THank you sir! it helps me alot.. but I have one more question. what if I want to get the name of the students whose birthdays are in the month selected?

Comment: wow! amazing! I get it now. heres the code and it helps me finish my work. SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%e %M') AS birthday, Lname,Fname,Mname
  FROM students
 WHERE MONTH(DOB) = 1
 ORDER BY DAY(DOB);

Comment: failed to enable constraints. one or more rows contains values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.. sir here's the error when I generate it to a reports.

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with this query specifically.  It means that you're populating a `DataTable` in a `DataSet` that is the child table for a `DataRelation` and you don't have all the corresponding rows in the parent `DataTable`.  If you want the parent data too then you must get that first.  If you don't want the parent data then get rid of the relation.